# Индексация MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица :

```
id | name   | age
1  | Den    | 29
2  | Alyona | 15
3  | Putin  | 89
4  | Petro  | 12
```

Есть запрос :

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE age <= 29 AND gender = 'male'`

Дабы выборка осуществлялась быстрее хочу использовать составной индекс:

`CREATE INDEX age_gender ON users(age, gender);` или

```
CREATE INDEX age_gender ON users(gender, age);
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему более правильно использовать 2-й случай?
Почему если `age` стоит первым, то не проводится индексация по полю `gender`?
(Понимаю , что загвоздка в том, что `age` ограничивается диапазоном, но не пойму конкретнее)

Comment: Разве там, откуда вы взяли этот пример, нет ответа на вопросы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В mysql индекс представляет собой B-tree(по крайней мере, тот который строите Вы). В MySQL есть ограничения при использовании B-tree индекса:

- при поиске по одному полю может использоваться только самая левая часть ключа(если индекс по (a,b) нельзя искать по b)
- нельзя пропускать столбцы индекса(если индекс по (a,b,c), при поиске по a,c использует индекс только для a)
- индекс будет использовать поля слева направо до первого поиска по диапазону, например a>10 или a LIKE 'word%' (Это Ваш случай. Если индекс по (age, gender), поиск age <= 29 AND gender = 'male', то первый поиск по дапазону происходит по полю age, а значит остальная часть индекса не сможет быть использована)

Я описал также случаи, которые не относятся к Вашему вопросу. Надеюсь будут полезны в будущем. 
Если кто-то вспомнит ещё какие-то правила - пишите в комментах, добавлю сюда.

Comment: У b-tree индекса (точнее у b+tree) нет такого ограничения. Это в mysql оптимизированный поиск не реализован, поэтому возникают такие ограничения. Если когда-нить такой поиск будет реализован (ведь b+tree индекс позволяет его осуществить), то и ограничений таких не будет и запросы работать будут одинаково.

Comment: BOPOH, действительно так. Поправил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто представить себе индекс. Грубо говоря, индекс - это заранее упорядоченные значения из базы. gender-age будет выглядеть так

```
1-20 *
1-20 *
1-22 *
1-29 *
1-40 
2-10
2-20
2-39
```

А age, gender - так

```
10-2
20-1 *
20-1 *
20-2
22-1 *
29-1 *
39-2
40-1
```

Из какого быстрее выбрать - в котором значения идут по порядку, или в котором вразнобой?

Comment: Да, видимо, пример настолько затасканный, что уже на автопилоте предполагается наличие `gender` в структуре :-)

Comment: А если изменить условие на `age < 29 OR age > 40`? Тот же "вразнобой" в обоих случаях будет. Да и поиск как бы не совсем так проходит, а на b+tree